# PHP : imagepng and imagejpeg output invalid 16x16 image

Tags: php, image

Problem on a remote server (while the same php script works on a local) is:

1) PNG image is loaded from a system path:

```
    $imgpath = "absolute/path/to/a/png/image";
    $img = imagecreatefrompng($imgpath);
```

File and folder where file is stored has proper chmod and chown setup and I can output correct image size (for test):

```
    echo imagesx($img)." x ".imagesy($img);
```

Above line outputs `256 x 64` which is expected image size. I assume this means that `$img` object is properly loaded from the file.

2) When I try to output the image using:

```
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($img);
    imagedestroy($img);
```

...browser shows an empty image of `16 x 16` pixel size.

[Screenshot of how it looks like](https://ibb.co/kuDKSK)

3) If I try to open the same file using direct http url, browser opens it correctly (expected `256 x 64` image with some colorful content).

[Here is how image looks like when opened with direct link](https://ibb.co/buxhEz)

4) If I remove `header('Content-type....`, imagepng outputs png file content as expected:

`�PNG  IHDR@z?>�    pHYs���+�IDATx��]ytչ����͒-�Y����$�� ��f!$� Jh M)-�+=��q�Bii�e����ihi d!!!�B�=^B�D��E��}��y���I�H��s��䜌>ݙ{�߽�~����ct�e���]���~....`

(showing only part of the output here)

5) When I compare the output to what I can see on remote server using nano, seems 100% match in bytes and in file size. Also file size is exactly the same if I download the image using direct URL in browser.

6) I've also tried to output image with different methods, such as `fpassthru` and `echo file_get_contents(...` and setting up header for that purpose (adding content size etc.). All resulted the same.

I'm going nuts here. Anyone has any idea what could be the problem?

P.S. request status is 200, no errors and no server errors in log file.

P.P.S. I have compared request and response headers when I open image with direct link and via PHP script. They are exactly the same.

Comment: By "_empty image of 16 x 16 pixel size._" you mean a transparent image? Or the "Missing image" placeholder of your browser? How do you output that image on your site? Any HTML we can see?

Comment: The proper test for loading is `if(!$img)...`. Try creating a solid red image from scratch without referring to the filesystem `$im = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);` then `$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);` then `imagefill($im, 0, 0, $red);`

Comment: @kerbholz I have added screenshot of how it looks. Good point!

Comment: @MarkSetchell image is definitely loaded correctly because I can get imagesx and imagesy from $img object and they are of expected size.

Comment: Could it be there are CSS styles applied to the image? And you output it via `<img src="captcha-image.php">` or something?

Comment: @kerbholz no html/css is echoed actually. PHP only outputs what is shown above: sets header to image/png and outputs image bytes.

Comment: I'm a little confused, if you don't use an `<img>` tag, where's the difference between "_When I try to output the image using:_" and "_If I try to open the same file using direct http url_"? There should be a PHP script that generates this image and outputs it.

Comment: @kerbholz my problem is exactly that: PHP script outputs an image (eg. http://domain/showimage.php) and it shows 16x16 empty image (screenshot included). When I try to open the same file with direct URL in browser (eg. http://domain/image.png), it shows a correct image.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now, you're actually saving that image. You could try to remove `domain/image.png` and see if it gets created the correct way. Another thing you might try is use `Content-Type` instead of `Content-type` (case) in the header. Other than that I can't help :|

Comment: Have you checked, that the PHP and GD version is the same on both machines? Check `phpinfo()` (or @CLI `php -i | grep "GD Version"` & `php -i | grep "PHP Version"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I can reproduce this issue is when I output content before changing the header. Can you please check if there are no spaces before `<?php` tag and no other possible outputs

Comment: That was spot-on! P.S. in one of my .php classes there was indeed a new-liner before <?php. And for some strange reason, on my local it worked (php7.2) and on remote did not (php7.0) - which is what @feeela suggested to check :-) Thanks guys!

Comment: @feeela thank you for pointing this out, I'll try to make my answers better. And in this case, if you please refer to first paragraph in "But I can't write a good answer without more information!" - it looks exactly like in the example they provided. Maybe it looks like a comment, but some answers are like that :)